# What is the practical difference between an unencrypted, password-protected Mac and a FileVault encrypted Mac?

Tags: security, encryption, filevault

In efforts to learn how to protect a new Apple-silicone laptop from theft, I'm trying to decide whether or not to use FileVault.

I know it encrypts all your files on-the-fly, and the barrier to the files is just a password. If FileVault is off and I just set a normal user password, it's also a password barrier. How else can someone access my files with FileVault off?

Comment: In modern hardware, disk encryption carries basically no cost in term of performance or power needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple Silicon Macs all have encryption of the drive enabled at all times - no matter if you enable FileVault or not.

This means that the contents of the drive is encrypted (i.e. not immediately readable) - and you won't be able to just take out the drive (which is in itself a more difficult operation than usual) and read it from another computer. It is certainly not something that an average home user would ever be able to do.

The practical difference between having a password-protected system with FileVault disabled, and a password-protected system with FileVault enabled is how difficult it is to get to your files without knowing your password.

For a password-protected system with FileVault enabled, it is practically impossible for the average home user or even IT professional to get to your files without knowing your password. If you're directly targeted by a nation state, circumstances might be different - but that's not the practical world most of us live in.

For a password-protected system with FileVault disabled, you will ordinarily be required a password to login. However, there are ways to circumvent that and access your files, that could be accessible to home users. You're certainly exposed to flaws (bugs) in lots of different software packages that could help a malicious person gain access to your files.

A user would be able to just boot the Mac holding down Opt-R to enter Recovery Mode and gain access to the files. On non-Apple Silicon systems, this access can be somewhat blocked by enabling a Firmware Password, which means that booting into Recovery Mode requires a password. However, for some older machines it is possible for Apple (and possibly others) to reset that Firmware password. On recent Intel machines, removing the Firmware Password automatically erases the contents of the disk.

On your Apple Silicon system, there's no concept of a Firmware Password as such. Instead the system automatically protects access to the Recovery Mode with your password when you have enabled File Vault.

So all in all, I would highly recommend enabling FileVault on your computer.

There's absolutely no performance impact in doing so (remember that your drive is encrypted no matter what). The main risk or concern involved in enabling FileVault is that you might forgot your password and recovery key - this can be somewhat mitigated by letting the system store a recovery key with your iCloud account.

Comment: A difference with FileVault could be if you have multiple user accounts on the Macbook. Some may be allowed to unlock FileVault while others aren't. The latter means that they have their own account, but they need an authorized user to unlock FileVault first when the computer starts. May be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: Sure - but this question was about protecting against theft of the computer.

Comment: That’s why I wrote in a comment, not in a separate answer. I thought it’s nonetheless an interesting aspect.

Comment: Ah yes - in that light it definitely is. I can see some home-user scenarios where that difference might come in handy!

Comment: Thanks for the super informative answer. I’m still feeling a bit unclear on how a thief could access my files without the password though (with FileVault off). And even more unclear about the difference between an already-encrypted Apple Silicone computer with and without FileVault. For instance, is a non-FileVault Apple Silicone computer susceptible to no-password file access via recovery mode like non Apple silicone macs?

Comment: I'm not going to detail exactly how the thief should do this on a non-FileVault system, but let's just say that any way that lets the thief bypass the login screen or boot from separate software, will allow them full access to all the files. That is not possible if FileVault is enabled.

Comment: For the second part: Yes, files can be accessed without your password from Recovery Mode on an Apple Silicon Mac if you have not enabled File Vault. If you have enabled File Vault, your password is always required (or alternatively a recovery key if you have set such a thing).

Comment: @etudes If you physically remove the disk and attach it to another computer (which boots from its own drive), your password is not required to access the disk.

Comment: @nohillside You cannot access the files that way - just check my comments on the deleted answer.

Comment: @jksoegaard AFAIK even removing the SSD from an M1 Mac is a challenge :-) The remark was more generally regarding internal drives of non-M1 Macs

Comment: Would changing the security policy with recovery mode's Startup Security Utility have an effect on this? To use an app from UAD, I'll need to change it to Reduced Security with "Allow user management of kernel extensions from identified developers" checked.

Comment: Have an effect on what exactly?

Comment: Would it have an effect on the security of my data in the event of a theft — i.e. would that introduce new ways a thief could access my data? (In either case, FileVault on or off).

Comment: In the event of a theft where the computer is turned off, then if you have File Vault enabled the security policy setting doesn’t make much difference. Your data is secure. If you do not have File Vault enabled, it does make a significant difference. Always enable File Vault.

Comment: As someone who uses Pro Tools for work, I'm advised not to enable File Vault :( Pro Tools officially doesn't support FV. https://avid.secure.force.com/pkb/articles/compatibility/Pro-Tools-System-Requirements And UAD requires my security settings to be reduced. Feeling quite stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: The recommendation from Avid is most probably bogus. Their argument is that it is an “optimization” to have it disabled - which isn’t true on modern systems. So most probably this is an old recommendation that they simply haven’t come around to update for Apple Silicon and Intel T2 systems. Just enable File Vault.

Comment: Roger that, I'll give it a try. If I notice a bunch of errors, I'll try disabling it and see if it reduces problems. Thanks for all the advice, seriously appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone reading the above answer: In Intel Macs with T2 chips, and in Apple Silicon Macs, Apple has dedicated hardware that performs Filevault's on-the-fly encryption/decryption, so there is no performance impact from using it.  But for Intel Macs without this (e.g., 2019 and older iMacs), the on-the-fly encryption/decryption is done in software, and that does create a modest performance hit, which could lead to a small decrease in responsiveness (or a larger decrease, if your Mac uses an HD instead of an SSD).