# Question regarding Filevault on M1 computers

Tags: security, encryption, filevault, apple-silicon

I wanted to ask this in this thread:

[What is the practical difference between an unencrypted, password-protected Mac and a FileVault encrypted Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429132/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-an-unencrypted-password-protected-mac)?

but it wouldn't let me because I'm a new user. I'm curious as to why use FileValut if the hard drive in an M1 is already automatically encrypted. Two questions after reading the above thread:

1. jksoegaard, if you're reading this, or someone else who really knows their stuff: Would you recommend the "recovery key" or "use icloud" option for FileVault?
2. Just to be clear, and correct me if I'm wrong, but to access the M1 hard drive, you need to boot it up into recovery mode, choose to share the disk, and at that point it will ask for your password, correct? Are you saying that, at that stage, it is possible for someone to bypass that password requirement and gain access to the content of the (automatically encrypted by the OS) hard drive?

Comment: Just as note we don't have threads here, we have questions and answers. So you have done the correct thing in asking a new question even if you had reputation to comment

Answer (score 0):

Choosing between having a recovery key or using the iCloud method is largely a matter of personal choice. Neither option is universally "better":

If you're particularly worried about the iCloud system being exploited, you might prefer storing the key yourself. If you're the type that tends to forget where you put that important key when you need it a few years later, you might prefer going the iCloud way.

As for your second question; no, sharing the disk is not a requirement in order to access the disk in Recovery mode. For most practical purposes, you cannot rely on the user account password to protect the data contents of your computer from a possible intruder. Enabling FileVault is on another level of protection entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm curious, which method (icloud, or key) do you personally use, and why? (if you don't mind saying) I'm not necessarily worried about the iCloud system being exploited, but maybe I should be? What is your thought on that?

Comment: If you're asking as an ordinary home user - i.e. for personal use - then I see nothing wrong with choosing the iCloud method. For most, that would be the preferred option.